# Diff files in two folders ignoring the first line

Tags: bash, unix, diff, gnu

I have two folders of files that I want to diff, except I want to ignore the first line in all the files. I tried

```
  diff -Nr <(tail -n +1 folder1/) <(tail -n +1 folder2/)
```

but that clearly isn't the right way.

Comment: What about making a recursive copy of the two folders with `cp -r`, and then using `find -exec sed -i 1d {} \;` to remove the first lines from the copies; you can than run normal `diff -r`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first lines that you want to ignore have a distinctive format that can be matched by a POSIX regular expression, then you can use `diff`'s `--ignore-matching-lines=...` option to tell it to ignore those lines.

Failing that, the approach you want to take probably depends on your exact requirements. You say you "want to diff" the files, but it's not obvious exactly how faithfully your resulting output needs to match what you would get from `diff -Nr` if it supported that feature. (For example, do you need the line numbers in the diff to correctly identify the line numbers in the original files?)

The most precisely faithful approach would probably be as follows:

- Copy each directory to a fresh location, using `cp --recursive ...`.
- Edit the first line of each file to prepend a magic string like `IGNORE_THIS_LINE::`, using something like `find -type f -exec sed -i '1 s/^/IGNORE_THIS_LINE::/' '{}' ';'`.
- Use `diff -Nr --ignore-matching-lines=^IGNORE_THIS_LINE:: ...` to compare the results.

  - Pipe the output to `sed s/IGNORE_THIS_LINE:://`, so as to filter out any occurrences of `IGNORE_THIS_LINE::` that still show up (due to being within a few lines of non-ignored differences).

Answer (score 2):

Using *Process Substitution* ist the correct way to create intermediate input file descriptors. But `tail` doesnt work on folders. Just iterate over all the files in the folder:

```sh
for f in folder1/*.txt; do
    tail -n +2 $f | diff - <(tail -n +2 folder2/$(basename $f))
done
```

Note i used `+2` instead of `+1`. `tail` line numbering starts at line `1` not `0`